# What is the TFS equivalent of SVN checkout to new folder?

Tags: svn, tfs

I've recently moved from an SVN shop to a place that uses TFS. In the old place, I got into a routine of checking my project out to a new folder after a checkin, so I could build it there in isolation, and check that I hadn't forgotten to include any files, etc.

In TFS, the obvious way to do this would seem to be to change the local path that my project is mapped to, "Get Latest Version", then change the mapped folder back again. That seems a little clunky. Is there a better way that I'm missing?

(Yes, ideally, there'd be a gated check-in, a build server, and all mod-cons, but for the time being I'm after a simple way to check if I've made a mistake.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would recommend using separate workspace to do clean builds. After you checkin:

- go to the separate workspace, which you don't use to work (no pending changes)
- do "get latest"
- optionally use tfpt scorch from tfs powertools which will remove build artifacts etc.
- build there

I would not recommend frequently changing mappings in the same workspace, much better just have different workspaces.

Good luck!

Comment: That did the trick nicely, thank you. (And yes, there were problems with the build! :/ )